# different values assignment on two ways tables or dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

how can I add a few columns like in dF2 to expand the year after year annual cash value? Thanks.

```
dF = pd.DataFrame({'num_year':[2.4,1.5,1],
                   'annual_value':[10,20,30]})
```

I want to get some a table like this:

```
dF2 = pd.DataFrame({'num_year':[2.4,1.5,1],
              'annual_value':[10,20,30],
              'year1':[10,20,30],
              'year2':[10,10,0],
              'year3':[4,0,0]
              })
```

Comment: What's ur attempt in solving the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I use `divmod`, the creaet the `list` then just `mul` the `annual_value` and `join` it back

```
def sdiv(a, b):
    q, r = np.divmod(a, b)
    return [1]*int(q) + [r]
dF2=dF.join(pd.DataFrame(dF.num_year.map(lambda x :sdiv(x,1)).tolist(),index=dF.index).\
        fillna(0).mul(dF['annual_value'],axis=0).add_prefix('year'))
dF2
Out[87]: 
   num_year  annual_value  year0  year1  year2
0       2.4            10     10   10.0    4.0
1       1.5            20     20   10.0    0.0
2       1.0            30     30    0.0    0.0
```